# Switching D3D12 device in UWP app causes CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow to fail

Tags: c++, uwp, direct3d12

I have a UWP app which may need to switch between D3D12 devices. For that, I would create a new swap chain by calling `CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow`. However, this operation fails with `E_ACCESSDENIED` if I do a switch (it works in the first call) and the debug layer prints the following message:

> DXGI ERROR: IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain: Only one flip model swap chain can be associate with an HWND, IWindow, or composition surface at a time. ClearState() and Flush() may need to be called on the D3D11 device context to trigger deferred destruction of old swapchains. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #297: ]

On D3D11, I can do exactly this, call `ClearState` and `Flush` on the device context before creating a new swap chain, but I have no idea what the equivalent would be in D3D12.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Multiple adaptors or multiple queues are the only sensible things to do

Comment: You can try using [ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::ClearState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12graphicscommandlist-clearstate) first.

Comment: I want to be able to switch the GPUs on laptops with an Intel and an NVIDIA one at runtime. In order to do that, I would need to be able to remove the existing swap chain from the core window and create a new one on the other device.

Comment: the gpu's are called "adaptors", are you sure the swapchain is being destroyed? Use `ID3D12DebugDevice::ReportLiveDeviceObjects` to check (give you swapchain a name). The D3D12 runtime may hold on to a reference for a few seconds, so try a sleep before creating a new one

Comment: Actually, I am not. My current hypothesis is that the UWP CoreWindow class keeps the swap chain alive, which then causes the issue when recreating it. On Win32, I would just drop the window, recreate the device and make a new swap chain for the new window. However, UWP really does not like me destroying the CoreWindow.

Comment: It might be just the D3D12 runtime

Comment: Yeah, I will try @JunjieZhu-MSFT's `ClearState` thing when I get back to the office tomorrow. My understanding is that this should fix the runtime part.

Comment: `ClearState` and waiting for a fence after it seems to be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be resolved by calling `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::ClearState` and waiting for a fence before creating a new swap chain.